# How to install libjpeg62-turbo on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial)?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation

To install a package onto Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial), I'm being prompted with "Package libjpeg62-turbo is not installed." ..  I see it listed in https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjpeg62-turbo however what is the best way to install this onto Xenial?  Should I be searching for an equivalent package that contains the needed binaries and if so how can I best locate that package?

Comment: Debian & Ubuntu use different package names for same source. In ubuntu it's `libjpeg-turbo8` so you'd be well-advised to stick with that & find a more suitable version of the un-named package your trying to install

Comment: HI, Can you please show you have install this package from there and what will be the link. i Cannot find link,Can you  please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04, available is **libjpeg62-dev**, libjpeg-dev, libjpeg8-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev

However, installing `libjpeg62-dev` will remove these (if installed) :

```
libarmadillo-dev libfox1.6-dev libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-dev libjpeg-dev \
libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libmlpack-dev libnetcdf-dev libtiff5-dev
```

`libjpeg´ https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjpeg&searchon=names

Comment: Thank you - turns out the package that depends on this library was coded specifically to look for libjpeg62-turbo on Debian Jessie so I was forced to switch over to that OS.  Once there the installation worked fine.  Would like to work out how to replace the dependency with libjpeg-turbo8 but that will have to wait until another time .. Thanks again and for the search resource

Answer (score -1):

You can find package here:
http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo

Run:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Debian packages shouldn't be mixed with Ubuntu's.